# How to perform simple authentication and auth with social networks without Devise using omniauth? RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization

I have seen casts. Understand everything, But how to perform 2 in 1 auth with social networks not using Devise? What should be in SessionsController, action create? Or I need to create specific action?

For example in such controller, how to check in what way user wants to auth

```
def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed explanation of implementing this

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?view=asciicast
```

Just download the [source](http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/sources/241-simple-omniauth.zip) and run the app for better understanding

Comment: Thanks. I understant how to perform only with soc networks or only simple auth. I want to understand how to implement both together

Comment: [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) cast for auth from scratch, and I don't remember but there was some cast for implementing both together

Answer (score 1):

Please read this blog post to understand how to integrate Rails app with other Social Network such as Facebook and Twitter - http://www.manaslutech.com/blogs/3-Ruby-on-Rails-integration-with-Facebook-and-Twitter